# How to use SCNBufferBindingBlock in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, shader, scenekit, metal

I'm looking at SceneKit's handle binding method with the SCNBufferBindingBlock call back as described here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnbufferbindingblock

Does anyone have an example of how this works?

```
    let program = SCNProgram()
    program.handleBinding(ofBufferNamed: "", frequency: .perFrame) { (steam, theNode, theShadable, theRenderer) in

    }
```

To me it reads like I can use a *.metal shader on a SCNNode without having to go through the hassle of SCNTechniques....any takers?

Answer (score 4):

Just posting this in case someone else came here looking for a concise example. Here's how `SCNProgram`'s `handleBinding()` method can be used with *Metal*:

First define a data structure in your `.metal` shader file:

```
struct MyShaderUniforms {
    float myFloatParam;
    float2 myFloat2Param;
};
```

Then pass this as an argument to a shader function:

```
fragment half4 myFragmentFunction(MyVertex vertexIn [[stage_in]], 
                                  constant MyShaderUniforms& shaderUniforms [[buffer(0)]]) {
    ...
}
```

Next, define the same data structure in your *Swift* file:

```
struct MyShaderUniforms {
    var myFloatParam: Float = 1.0
    var myFloat2Param = simd_float2()
}
```

Now create an instance of this data structure, changes its values and define the `SCNBufferBindingBlock`:

```
var myUniforms = MyShaderUniforms()
myUniforms.myFloatParam = 3.0

...

program.handleBinding(ofBufferNamed: "shaderUniforms", frequency: .perFrame) { (bufferStream, node, shadable, renderer) in
    bufferStream.writeBytes(&myUniforms, count: MemoryLayout<MyShaderUniforms>.stride)
}
```

Here, the string passed to `ofBufferNamed:` corresponds to the argument name in the fragment function. The block's `bufferStream` property then contains the user-defined data type `MyShaderUniforms` which can then be written to with updated values.

Answer (score 3):

The `.handleBinding(ofBufferNamed:frequency:handler:)` method registers a block for SceneKit to call at render time for binding a Metal buffer to the shader program. This method can only be used with Metal or OpenGL shading language based programs. `SCNProgram` object helps perform this custom rendering. Program object contains a vertex shader and a fragment shader. Using a program object completely replaces SceneKit’s rendering. Your shaders take input from SceneKit and become responsible for all transform, lighting and shading effects you want to produce. Use `.handleBinding()` method to associate a block with a Metal shader program to handle setup of a buffer used in that shader.

> Here's a link to [Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnprogram) on SCNProgram class.

Also you need an instance method `writeBytes(_:count:)` that copies all your necessary data bytes into the underlying Metal buffer for use by a shader.

`SCNTechnique`class specifically made for post-processing SceneKit's rendering of a scene using additional drawing passes with custom Metal or OpenGL shaders. Using `SCNTechnique` you can create such effects as color grading or displacement, motion blur and render ambient occlusion as well as other render passes.

Here is a first code's excerpt how to properly use .handleBinding() method:

```
func useTheseAPIs(shadable: SCNShadable,
                  bufferStream: SCNBufferStream
                  voidPtr: UnsafeMutableRawPointer,
                  bindingBlock: @escaping SCNBindingBlock, 
                  bufferFrequency: SCNBufferFrequency,
                  bufferBindingBlock: @escaping SCNBufferBindingBlock,
                  program: SCNProgram) {

    bufferStream.writeBytes(voidPtr, count: 4) 

    shadable.handleBinding!(ofSymbol: "symbol", handler: bindingBlock)
    shadable.handleUnbinding!(ofSymbol: "symbol", handler: bindingBlock)

    program.handleBinding(ofBufferNamed: "pass", 
                          frequency: bufferFrequency,
                          handler: bufferBindingBlock)
}
```

And here is a second code's excerpt:

```
let program = SCNProgram()
program.delegate = self as? SCNProgramDelegate
program.vertexShader = NextLevelGLContextYUVVertexShader
program.fragmentShader = NextLevelGLContextYUVFragmentShader

program.setSemantic(
    SCNGeometrySource.Semantic.vertex.rawValue, 
    forSymbol: NextLevelGLContextAttributeVertex, 
    options: nil)

program.setSemantic(
    SCNGeometrySource.Semantic.texcoord.rawValue, 
    forSymbol: NextLevelGLContextAttributeTextureCoord, 
    options: nil)

if let material = self._material {
    material.program = program

    material.handleBinding(ofSymbol: NextLevelGLContextUniformTextureSamplerY, handler: { 
        (programId: UInt32, location: UInt32, node: SCNNode?, renderer: SCNRenderer) in
            glUniform1i(GLint(location), 0);
    }) 
    material.handleBinding(ofSymbol: NextLevelGLContextUniformTextureSamplerUV, handler: { 
        (programId: UInt32, location: UInt32, node: SCNNode?, renderer: SCNRenderer) in
            glUniform1i(GLint(location), 1);
    })
}
```

> Also, look at [Simulating refraction in SceneKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381638/simulating-refraction-in-scenekit/41824095#41824095)
>    SO post.